# use another matchings in some matching

Tags: f#, match

It's not really hard trouble but as I'm learning language I want my code being sorta elegant and I don't like this :

```
            match aver with
                | 1 -> @" GROUP BY
                            DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(HOUR, DT.[Date]),
                            (DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date]) / 10)"
                | 2 -> @" GROUP BY
                            DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(HOUR, DT.[Date])"
                | 3 -> @" GROUP BY
                            DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date])"
                | 4 -> @" GROUP BY
                            DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date])"
                | _ -> @" GROUP BY
                            DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(HOUR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date])"
```

because I really want it alike this :

```
            match aver with
                | 4 -> @" GROUP BY
                            DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                            DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date])"
                | 3 -> 2 + @",DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date])"
                | 2 -> 3 + @",DATEPART(HOUR, DT.[Date])"
                | 1 -> 3 + @", (DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date]) / 10)"
                | _ -> 3 + @", DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date])"
```

is there some way to use another matchings in some matching ?

Comment: I'd argue that you shouldn't be generating SQL in this manner.

Comment: @OJ why so ... ? I need to use generated sql in another ways later.

Comment: If you integrate any user input into generated SQL, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let rec myFuncName = function
    | 4 -> @" GROUP BY
                DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
                DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date])"
    | 3 -> myFuncName 4 + ",DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date])"
    | 2 -> myFuncName 3 + ",DATEPART(HOUR, DT.[Date])"
    | 1 -> myFuncName 2 + ",(DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date]) / 10)"
    | _ -> myFuncName 2 + ",DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date])"
```

Not the most efficient, but it should demonstrate what you're looking for.

Comment: You asked for weird, you got weird. :) I would prefer your original code for readability.

Comment: If there is no better construction, then - yes. I asked if maybe I don't know some case-like F# syntax.